# Restricting to Single Instance of Executable with Golang

Tags: windows, go, mutex

I need to only allow one instance of my Golang executable at a time. I'm not sure how to use a Global Mutex to make sure no other instances are running.

This would be running on a Windows Machine.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/tBEh_eGl8jY

Comment: Good choice for the new accepted answer :)

Comment: i guess the simplest solution is to use https://github.com/juju/fslock

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this topic is a bit old, but I needed it recently on Windows and I'll post here how I did it in case someone else needs.

Thx to @VonC for pointing me in the right direction.

```
var (
    kernel32        = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    procCreateMutex = kernel32.NewProc("CreateMutexW")
)

func CreateMutex(name string) (uintptr, error) {
    ret, _, err := procCreateMutex.Call(
        0,
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(name))),
    )
    switch int(err.(syscall.Errno)) {
    case 0:
        return ret, nil
    default:
        return ret, err
    }
}

// mutexName starting with "Global\" will work across all user sessions
_, err := CreateMutex("SomeMutexName")
```

I created a lib with a more complete example: https://github.com/rodolfoag/gow32

Thx!

Comment: Thank you! Can confirm this worked great for me. I like that it doesn't have the pitfalls of some of the other commonly suggested approaches.

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to be a cross-platform solution (beside writing a file, and looking for that file at start time).

On Windows, this [thread reports](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/tBEh_eGl8jY)

> the recommended approach (and the one that has worked great for me) is to use the [`CreateSemaphore` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
>   If the name you specify starts with "`Global\`", then the semaphore is unique for the entire system and a second attempt to open it will fail.

This is a kernel32 call, which has some [wrapper in Go available](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32/blob/master/kernel32.go).

[kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) adds in the comments:

> look at the Go source code around the pkg\syscall hierarchy -- it contains a good wealth of examples on how to call out to DLLs on Windows using syscalls (and that's how you access anything in Windows API).

That would be [**`syscall/dll_windows.go`**](http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/dll_windows.go). (And here [is a gist](https://gist.github.com/wendal/5319463))

> The [odbc package by brainman](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc) is another example of direct API calls on Windows -- possibly easier to digest.

Like [`api/zapi_windows.go`](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/blob/master/api/zapi_windows.go).

Comment: I'm not seeing the function call in the wrapper. Perhaps it's not totally complete?

Comment: @KevinPostal yes, it isn't complete, I was referring to it just as an example on how it is possible to call win dll from Go.

Comment: @KevinPostal, look at the Go source code around the `pkg\syscall` hierarchy -- it contains a good wealth of examples on how to call out to DLLs on Windows using syscalls (and that's how you access anything in Windows API). The `odbc` package by brainman is another example of [direct API calls on Windows](https://code.google.com/p/odbc/source/browse/api/zapi_windows.go) -- possibly easier to digest.

Comment: @kostix Good points. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility; And I have added some links to those sources.

Answer (score 6):

You could use sockets, simple to use and will work on everything really.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const (
    INSTANCE_PORT = 9292
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", INSTANCE_PORT))
    if err != nil {
        if strings.Index(err.Error(), "in use") != -1 {
            //optionally send command line arguments to the other instance
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Already running.")
            return
        } else {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            println("Error accept:", err.Error())
            return
        }
        go do_something_with(conn)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was considering this approach. Just difficult to know which port to use that would not potentially be in use.

Comment: There is a range of ephemeral ports that are first come first serve. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port

Comment: An ephemeral port won't work. The next instances will get a different port and will be able to listen to it.

Comment: You could make it configurable in some kinda file and warn the user that if the program can't start to change the port in that file.

Answer (score 4):

You could adapt the code from tendo's python library [source](http://tendo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tendo/singleton.html)

what they do is 
for windows :

creating a file made of the executable absolute path (well it's a library, so in your case, you can just define an identifier, to prevent you from "i put the executable in 2 places")

- For windows: trying first to remove the file if existing,  and if not creating the file with `os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_RDWR`
- For POSIX compatible systems: trying first to remove the file if existing and if not creating the file and acquiring a lock on it using `fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB`

any failure mean the program is already running

and then you can use a defer action to remove the lock (on posix system) and delete the file

Go permit you to create both version wit a build comment to tell which file to compile depending on your OS so you have

for unix system

```
// +build !windows

package main

import (
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func create_lock_file(filename string) (*os.File, error) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = syscall.Flock(int(file.Fd()), syscall.LOCK_EX|syscall.LOCK_NB)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return file, nil
}
```

for windows:

```
// +build !windows

package main

import (
    "os"
)

func create_lock_file(filename string) (*os.File, error) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(filename); err == nil {
        err = os.Remove(filename)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

    }
    return os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_EXCL|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
}
```

and a test

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    _, err := create_lock_file("plop.lock")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error ", err.Error())
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("end ")
}
```

I've started a library out of it [that you can find here](https://github.com/allan-simon/go-singleinstance)

Answer (score 0):

Improvements to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39547857/9935654). (I am unsure if this answer will distort the original meaning, so I have written a new answer.)

Features:

- [deprecated](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/489102d/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L89-L90): `StringToUTF16Ptr` is deprecated. Use `UTF16PtrFromString` instead.
- Add the `CloseHandle` so that you can cancel the `CreateMutexW`.

```golang
package _test

import (
    "syscall"
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    kernel32         = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    procCreateMutexW = kernel32.NewProc("CreateMutexW")
    procCloseHandle  = kernel32.NewProc("CloseHandle")
)

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexW#return-value
func CreateMutexW(proc *syscall.LazyProc, name string) (uintptr, error) {
    if proc.Name != "CreateMutexW" {
        panic("proc.Name != CreateMutexW")
    }
    lpName, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(name) // LPCWSTR
    if handleID, _, err := proc.Call(
        0,
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpName)),
    ); err.(syscall.Errno) == 0 {
        return handleID, nil
    } else {
        return handleID, err
    }
}

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN
func CloseHandle(proc *syscall.LazyProc, handle uintptr) error {
    if proc.Name != "CloseHandle" {
        panic("proc.Name != CloseHandle")
    }
    val, _, err := proc.Call(handle)
    if val == 0 {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func TestCreateMutexW(t *testing.T) {
    handle, err := CreateMutexW(procCreateMutexW, "hello world")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }

    _, err = CreateMutexW(procCreateMutexW, "hello world")
    if err == nil || err != syscall.ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS {
        t.Error("should panic")
    }

    if err = CloseHandle(procCloseHandle, handle); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    // We can create again since we have closed.
    handle, _ = CreateMutexW(procCreateMutexW, "hello world")
    if err = CloseHandle(procCloseHandle, handle); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```